C# .editorConfig Local Variable Naming rule not working
I'm working on a .Net FrameWork v4.5.2, Web API Project.
I'm working to apply a rule in project to ensure local variables in the method are in Camel case
editorconfig changes are as follows
# Naming rules
dotnet_naming_rule.local_variables_should_be_camel_case.severity = suggestion
dotnet_naming_rule.local_variables_should_be_camel_case.symbols = local
dotnet_naming_rule.local_variables_should_be_camel_case.style = camel_case
 
# Symbol specifications
dotnet_naming_symbols.local.applicable_kinds = local
dotnet_naming_symbols.local.applicable_accessibilities = *
dotnet_naming_symbols.local.required_modifiers =

# Naming styles
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case.required_prefix =
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case.required_suffix =
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case.word_separator =
dotnet_naming_style.camel_case.capitalization = camel_case

I've ensured that the EditorConfig file is located in the root directory of my project.
Despite of these , the camel case rule for local variables is not being enforced.
Expected behavior: If local variables are mistakenly written in Pascal case instead of camel case, the IDE should display a suggestion indicating a naming convention violation as per the EditorConfig settings
I'm seeking guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

What do you mean by "not working"? What exactly are you seeing?

Despite configuring the EditorConfig file to enforce camel case for local variables, the desired behavior is not being observed.

But what is the desired behaviour? You need to be explicit or nobody can help you.

The desired behavior is that the IDE should provide a suggestion  when local variables are written in Pascal case instead of camel case, based on the rules specified in the EditorConfig file

What happens if you add [*.cs] line at the top?

Did you ever figure this out?
